# System of two quadratic equations: how the solution changes with the parameters

Tags: polynomials, systems-of-equations

Here are two quadratic equations with respect to two non-negative variables $x_1$ and $x_2$

$x_1((2-\gamma^2) c_1 - \gamma c_2 - 2 x_1)(1-\theta)+(2-\gamma^2) (2 (c_1 -\frac{(2-\gamma^2) x_1 + \gamma x_2}{4-5 \gamma^2 + \gamma^4} )x_1 + (c_2 - \frac{(2-\gamma^2) x_2 + \gamma x_1}{4 - 5 \gamma^2 + \gamma^4})(-\gamma x_1 + \gamma^2 x_2))\theta =0$,

$x_2((2-\gamma^2) c_2 - \gamma c_1 - 2 x_2)(1-\theta)+(2-\gamma^2) (2 (c_2 -\frac{(2-\gamma^2) x_2 + \gamma x_1}{4-5 \gamma^2 + \gamma^4} )x_2 + (c_1 - \frac{(2-\gamma^2) x_1 + \gamma x_2}{4 - 5 \gamma^2 + \gamma^4})(-\gamma x_2 + \gamma^2 x_1))\theta =0$.

where $\theta \in [0,1]$, $\gamma \in [0,1)$, $c_1,c_2 >0$ are parameters.

The question is, given $\theta $ and $\gamma$, when the parameters $(c_1,c_2)$ change from $(c,c)$ to $(c+\delta, c)$ where $\delta >0$, how would the nonnegative solution $(x_1^\ast, x_2^\ast)$ to the above system of equations change? i.e., $x_i^\ast, i =1,2$ become larger or smaller?

Comment: Differentiate both sides by $c_1$. Only $c_1$ itself and $x_1, x_2$ depend on $c_1$. Everything else are just constants. This will give you equations you can solve for $\dfrac{dx_1}{dc_1}$ and $\dfrac{dx_2}{dc_1}$. They will tell you how $x_1, x_2$ change with respect to changes in $c_1$.